# foreach with list in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to access numbers from list/vector, in general when I call normally not getting issue. But when I use it with foreach or for loop getting NULL as a result
Ex1:

```
aa<- c(7, 4, 10)
bb <- list(90,87,45)

aa[1] will result 7, bb[1] result 90 this is pretty straight forward
```

But when I try with for or foreach loop:

```
for(i in aa) aa[i]
or
for(i in aa) {bb[i]}

not getting any result 

ex2:

foreach(i = aa) %dopar% {aa[i]}
foreach(i = aa) %dopar% bb[i]

getting result as Null
```

Could some one please help and correct above code

Comment: this question does not have to do with python. parallel.forloop is related to C#. I will be removing these tags

Comment: What did you want `for(i in aa) aa[i]` to do exactly? `for` loops in R have no return value, they are just a control statement. If you were trying to use `aa` to index into `bb`, you can just do `bb[aa]`, for example `aa <- c(3,1); bb <- list(10,20,30); bb[aa]` (in your example `aa` are not all valid indexes in your `for(i in aa) {bb[i]}` loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting any result because `for` loop does not return anything. You can access the variables in `for` loop which can be demonstrated with a `print` statement.

```
for(i in seq_along(aa)) print(aa[i])

#[1] 7
#[1] 4
#[1] 10
```

Comment: Thank you @RonakShah and its really helpfull.

Comment: do you any answer for "foreach" loop?

Comment: I don't use `foreach` but it should work the same `foreach(i = seq_along(aa)) %dopar% {print(aa[i])}`

Answer (score 0):

For each iterates over each element of the data structure. i is each element not the index to the element

```
aaa <- foreach(i = aa, .combine=c) %dopar% {i}
```

If you want to iterate and access by elements you need to do something like

```
bbb <- foreach(i = 1:length(aa), .combine=c) %dopar% {bb[i]}
```

However, notice that has implications to the amount of information that is pass to each thread when running in parallel